# Sum based on criteria (one from a row and one from a column) in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

How do I write a formula to sum numerical values based on the text value in column A (match a name) and a month value in row 60? (match a specific month)

Currently manually input the row # for the correct name in column A:
`=sumif($60:$60,month(X$6),33:33)`

Row 60 is where the month value is, they need to match X6, row 33 is the name in column A that matches the right name.  Is there any way to make these two criteria dynamic instead of hard-coded row number (33)?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & work out a solution. You may also use the [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by docs community forum for ease of sharing.

Comment: Here is a demo sheet.  I would like to add formula to Summary tab with data in the POPTC tab to produce those numbers shown as samples for Student 1, 2, and 3.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mkGrRAeJ8b3ON_70BtjDyz2TBxbROOophje5nSdBQJM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this in `Cell_B3` of `Summary` tab. Make sure to clear the the `B3:G` range of any test_data prior to pasting this formula as it needs to expand freely to right + south*

```js
=map(A3:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,bycol(B1:G1,lambda(Λ,sum(ifna(filter(filter(POPTC!B2:AU,eomonth(POPTC!B1:AU1,)=eomonth(Λ,)),POPTC!A2:A=Σ))))))))
```

- *This also does not need the month helper column you created in `POPTC` tab. it directly looks into the dates accommodated in `row_1`*

[image]

[`MAP \ LAMBDA Explanation Vid`](https://youtu.be/kUur-tMdTbo)

***single cell formula (`this goes into Cell_B3`)***:

```js
=sum(ifna(filter(filter(POPTC!$B$2:$AU,eomonth(POPTC!$B$1:$AU$1,)=eomonth(B$1,)),POPTC!$A$2:$A=$A3)))
```

Comment: Oh the problem is, in the real form, these columns have to alternate with a different set of data for a different type of pts for each month, so I'll have to have other type of formula to the right...

Comment: standalone (single cell) formula updated in the answer.